# Movie about a vampire who is/was a cop who helps a girl in a bar

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

The title of the movie is the vampire's name. I believe that last name began with a C. The vampire was a cop/or a former cop. He helped a girl in a bar and this girl helped him when she found him near death in an alley.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! However, this isn't much to go on. Please take a look at our [guide on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your post with any additional information you can remember.

Answer (score 2):

I’m guessing this is the [Forever Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forever_Knight) pilot movie [Nick Knight](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097969/).

> Nick Knight is a 1989 American television film about Nick Knight, a
> centuries-old vampire working as a police detective in modern-day Los
> Angeles.
>
> Originally meant to be a pilot episode for a television series, it was
> not picked up at the time. However, in 1992, CBS picked up the series
> but produced the show in Canada as Forever Knight, re-filming the
> pilot (with the same plot) and using a completely different cast,
> except for John Kapelos.

I don't recommend it.  Not good.  Bad.  Very bad.

Comment: Aaaw, you don't like him driving a Fleetwood because the trunk is big enough to act as his coffin?